# I'm trying to make a command to show how many servers the discord bot is on but get i get the error "message is not defined"

Tags: discord.js

Heres my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: 'botinfo',
    description: 'embed test lol',
    
    execute(message, args) {
        const servers = client.guilds.cache.size;
        const serverinfoEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Random Title lol')
        .addFields(servers);
    }
} 
        
message.channel.send(botinfoEmbed)
```

And i get the error:

```
message.channel.send(botinfoEmbed)
^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

Note, I'm a complete noob at this so please explain in simple terms, Thanks

Comment: The message variable it outside the scope where it is defined in execute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the message.channel.send() inside the scope of execute() like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: 'botinfo',
    description: 'embed test lol',
    
    execute(message, args) {
        const servers = client.guilds.cache.size;

        const serverinfoEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Random Title lol')
        .addFields(servers);

        message.channel.send(botinfoEmbed);
    }
}
```

Out side of the scope of execute(), you will not have access to the parameters such as message or args.